# office 2013 WorkGroup Administration

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-office, office-interop

access to work group manager in access 2003 is available on menu `Security > workgroup administration` in newer access this menu has been removed but it is possible to access via macro or immediate windwow by runnin `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWorkgroupAdministrator`. 
another way to  join workgroup via security file is command prompt `path to 2007msaccess.exe" "path to mdb" /wrkgrp "path to secure.mdw"`it doesnt work correclty and client not join to workgroup/ . is there any alternative way to join via C# code or easier way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your command prompt is that you have the elements in the wrong order. It should be;

```
"Path to MSACCESS.EXE" /wrkgrp "Path to MDW" "Path to MDB"
```

I find the best way to set this up to to create a short-cut to the database with this string as the target.